# Retrieving categories from a website with DOMDocument and DOMXPath classes

Tags: php, html, xpath, web-scraping, domdocument

I have a PHP code to retrieve the categories from this website using the class name which is 'sub-title'. However, the output displays nothing. What am I doing wrong?

PHP code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$grep = new DoMDocument();
@$grep>loadHTMLFile("http://www.alibaba.com/Products",false,stream_context_create(array("http" => array("user_agent" => "any"))));

$finder = new DomXPath($grep);
$class = "sub-title";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$class')]");

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $span = $node->childNodes;
    echo $span->item(0)->nodeValue;

}

?>
```

Desired output:
Agriculture
Food & Beverage
Apparel
 
etc..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just target that particular element. By the way you current code has a typo on `$grep>loadHTMLFile`. It's missing `-` in `->`. I modified it a little bit.

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.alibaba.com/Products');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$finder = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $finder->query('//h4[@class="sub-title"]');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $sub_title = trim(explode("\n", trim($node->nodeValue))[0]) . '<br/>';
    echo $sub_title;
}
```

Comment: sure man glad to help, by they way just a sidenote, this tutorial may help you in dealing with this kind of situation, here's some [notes](http://blog.jmoz.co.uk/domdocument-domxpath-html-parsing/)

Comment: thanks :) I'll keep it in mind. This website scraping thing had me headache.

Answer (score 1):

To set a stream context when using `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile` to fetch HTML, use `libxml_set_streams_context`:

```
<?php

$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('user_agent' => 'any')));
libxml_set_streams_context($context);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.alibaba.com/Products');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//h4[@class="sub-title"]/a');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo trim($node->textContent) . "\n";
}
```